# How to direct IP address for my project war file web application?

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, server

I have a server on digital ocean with Ubuntu 14.04
I made web project with Java spring Maven MVC
I export a war file from Eclipse ide
I'm using Tomcat7

I moved the project under
var/lib/tomcat7/webapps and

Paste project_name.war file
only I can handle it with
my project working with this address
http://ipadress:8080/project_name

But I want to work it with
only ipadress

How can I do this?
What should I do?

Comment: You need allow ip based access for tomcat. Go to the server.xml and add  `useIPVHosts="true"` in Connector section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change your tomcat port to 80 in /etc/tomcat7/server.xml,

   < Connector port=80...
2. Remove the out-of-the-box ROOT/ directory from tomcat and rename your war file to ROOT.war before deploying it.

Deploy your war as (from your example) war_name.war and configure the context root in conf/server.xml to use your war file :

< Context path="" docBase="war_name" debug="0" reloadable="true">